# How would I get movement in a direction with 360 degree angles

Tags: javascript, pong

Im making a pong game and I want to make the ball have a speedX and a speedY that is added to the ball that makes it move along the X and Y axis but im not sure how to adjust those variables based off of the balls angle. In function ballPhysics() I need to replace the 0's with something to get the speed it should go along that axis. But if anyone finds anything else that should be worked on itd be great if you let me know thanks.

```js
let cvs, ctx;
let width = 600, height = 500;

let keysPressed = [];

class Wall {
  constructor(x, y, w, h, speed) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.speed = speed;
  }  
}

class Ball {
  constructor(x, y , w, h, speedX, speedY, angle) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.speedX = speedX;
    this.speedY = speedY;
    this.angle = angle;
  }
}
  
let left = new Wall(25, 250, 10, 100, 10); 
let right = new Wall(width-25, 250, 10, 100, 10)

let ball = new Ball(width/2, height/2, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0);

function ballPhysics() {
  ball.x += ball.speedX;
  ball.y += ball.speedY;
  
  ball.speedX = 0//figure out direction;
  ball.speedY = 0//figure out direction;
}

function start() {
  ball.x = width/2;
  ball.y = height/2;
  
  if(Math.random() < 0.5) {
    ball.angle = 90;
  } else {
    ball.angle = -90;
  }
  console.log(ball.angle);
}

function update() {
  setInterval(function () { 
    ballPhysics();
    for(let i = 0; i < keysPressed.length; i++) {
      if(keysPressed[i] == 'KeyW' && left.y >= 0) {
        left.y -= left.speed;
      }
      if(keysPressed[i] == 'KeyS' && left.y + left.h <= height) {
        left.y += left.speed;
      }
      if(keysPressed[i] == 'ArrowUp' && right.y >= 0) {
        right.y -= right.speed;
      }
      if(keysPressed[i] == 'ArrowDown' && right.y + right.h <= height) {
        right.y += right.speed;
      }
      if(keysPressed[i] == 'Space') {
        start();
      }
    }
  }, 16)
}

function renderPlayers() {
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
  ctx.fillRect(left.x, left.y, left.w, left.h);
  ctx.fillRect(right.x, right.y, right.w, right.h);
}

function renderBall() {
  ctx.fillStyle = '#0000FF';
  ctx.fillRect(ball.x, ball.y, ball.w, ball.h);
}

function render() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);
  
  renderBall();
  renderPlayers();
  
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}


window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  cvs = document.getElementById("cvs");
  ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

  cvs.width = width;
  cvs.height = height;
  
  update();
  render();
});

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if(!keysPressed.includes(e.code)) {
    keysPressed.push(e.code); 
  }
});

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  for(let i = 0; i < keysPressed.length; i++) {
    if(keysPressed[i] == e.code) {
      keysPressed.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#cvs {
  border: solid 1px black;
  background: #D1C3C3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Platformer</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />

    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas width="0" height="0" id="cvs"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you need the angle of the ball? Have you considered doing the opposite and getting the angle from the speed? Also, balls don't really have "angles", so this can get confusing...

Comment: Really I just need to figure out what the speeds are and i figured getting the direction which I named angle would help with that and make it easier to change the speeds when I add collision

Comment: SpeedX and speedY are giving you the velocity of the ball, i.e. a vector with a direction, so you already have the angle with that vector, why do you need another angle variable ?

Comment: You don't need the angle to bounce the ball. You just need to negate speedX or speedY.